# Oracle database link. Check for existence or overwrite?

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-link

I need to check if a database link already exists before I create one. How can I do that?

I am writing an SQL script that starts with this:

```
DROP DATABASE LINK mydblink
```

then I create one:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK mydblink
CONNECT TO testuser
IDENTIFIED BY mypswd
USING 'mypersonaldb'
```

I will of course get an error in the first step if the database link doesn't exists. And if I omit the first step and just go ahead and create a db link, I will again get an error saying that it already exists with the same name.

What can I do in order to check if the the database link already exists?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
  FROM dba_objects -- user_objects
 WHERE object_type = 'DATABASE LINK'
   AND object_name = 'ARGUS51P';
```

For example (untested):

```
declare
  l_link_cnt pls_integer := 0;
  l_sql varchar2(32767);
begin
  -- link creation sql (fill in details of how you want this created)
  l_sql := 'create public database link ...';

  select count(1)
  into l_link_cnt
  from dba_objects
  where object_type = 'DATABASE LINK'
  and object_name = 'SOME_LINK';

  -- create link if it doesn't exist yet
  if (l_link_cnt = 0) then
    -- create link 
    execute immediate l_sql;

  end if;

end;
```

Comment: I have nothing returned from this query even though I just created a link. What does count(1) do?

Comment: @OliverNilsen count(1) is really same as count(*).  I could have said count('Oliver') or count('tbone').

Comment: @Gaius in some situations the user running this script might not be the owner of the link (eg, owner might be PUBLIC).  But yes, often more than 1 way to skin a cat

Comment: Can you provide a sample code how I could check if the link exists, if not then create one, or else continue with the rest of the script. I am new to PL/SQL.

Comment: THX for the code. It turns out that  you cannot use, DDL statements inside a BEGIN block. Ah bummer

Comment: Is there a difference between `SELECT 1` and `SELECT count(1)`?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has no way to test for existence before a DROP or CREATE.  (Well, ok, you could write some PL/SQL, but, that's probably more trouble than it's worth.)  In Oracle scripting, it's pretty standard to simply do both the DROP and the CREATE in a script.  If the DROP errors out, so be it.  It won't affect execution of the script.

-Mark

Comment: I tried running it as a script. When it hits DROP DATABASE LINK statement it fails, and the rest of the script is not executed. Can you give me a hint what I could do in PL/SQL?

Comment: Does your script have an 'whenever sqlerror ...' clause?  Cause if you do, that's causing the exit.  If you just put a bunch of DROP/CREATE in a script and run it in SQL*Plus, it should work.  I'll look at updating my answer with PL/SQL example.